# Deploying Node.js, React.js, Express, and Socket.io Application on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, socket.io

enter image description hereSuccessfully deployed to Heroku and most of our application is working. However, our socket.io pieces (chat, view online users, game updates) are not functioning. We think this may be due to having an instance of socket initialized in the Board.js component and also in the App.js file but not sure if that is the issue or how to resolve.
GitHub: https://github.com/sranney/checkers 
Heroku App: https://afternoon-thicket-28146.herokuapp.com/

Any help is greatly appreciated [Photo1 1: Server Config for Http Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkPdB.png)    [Photo 2: Shows Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW2sm.png)    [Photo 3: Configuring socket in app component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhOjO.png)    [Photo 4: Importing socket into app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBs9H.png)

Comment: Hey Hermant I looked at the Heroku documentation here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets as well as these tutorials using Socket.io and Heroku:
http://robdodson.me/deploying-your-first-node-dot-js-and-socket-dot-io-app-to-heroku/
http://socket-io-chat.herokuapp.com/
Thanks!

Comment: sorry my bad i guess they support it now

Comment: No problem, these things constantly change!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing an io.connect statement in your server.js file. Check out this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5tRiFJuNOs) along with the source code in the description.